# Add subscriber with double-opt-in to mailjet?

Tags: mailjet

I want to add a subscriber to a contact list in Mailjet.

Is there any way I can put in a new email which triggers the double-opt-in mail? When I add a new subscriber via API he is immediately confirmed.

I can't use that widget, because I want to add users while registering on a shop.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible. I asked the dev support.

Comment: Also asked the support. It does not work out of the box. This is correct. But it is possible, if you code the flow on your own and let Mailjet send the confirmation email. That kind of works, but it's not great that Mailjet is unable to do a programmatic double-opt in when Mailchimp for example can.